# Problem(logical error) with the output of the code(file handling)

Tags: c++

[this is the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylNVC.gif) *I made the following code for my cs project but i am facing some logical errors which i am unable to fix i tried a lot but still i am unable to fix it so please help me,,*

as you can see in the picture above i entered male in sex but it is writing only ale in the file and there is a problem with the output

This is software which i made as a project for my practical exam it was working fine until my friend did some modifications to it whenever i am entering any record(using file) it is working fine(at least it seems to be) but when i am displaying the record some of the characters are missing i don't know why so please help me to fix it....*

*thank you*

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
class patient
{
     public:
     int year,date,month;
     int bno;
     char na[20],street[20],city[20],sex[8];
     patient()
      {
     bno=0;
     year=0;
     date=0;
     month=0;
     strcpy(na,NULL);
     strcpy(city,NULL);
     strcpy(street,NULL);
     strcpy(sex,NULL);
      }
    void enterdata()
     {
     cout<<"\nENTER THE NAME OF THE PATIENT \t\t-----\t\t";gets(na);
     cout<<"\nENTER GENDER\t\t\t\t-----\t\t";gets(sex);
     cout<<"\nASSIGN A UNIQUE BED NO. \t\t-----\t\t"; cin>>bno;
     cout<<"\nDATE OF BIRTH\nDATE  \t\t\t\t\t-----\t\t";cin>>date;
     cout<<"\nMONTH  \t\t\t\t\t-----\t\t";cin>>month;
     cout<<"\nYEAR  \t\t\t\t\t-----\t\t";cin>>year;
     cout<<"\nENTER STREET  \t\t\t\t-----\t\t";gets(street);
     cout<<"\nENTER CITY  \t\t\t\t-----\t\t";gets(city);

     }


    void showdata()
     {
       clrscr();
       cout<<" \t\t\tINFORMATION OF THE PATIENT\n";
       for(int vg=0;vg<78;vg++)
     cout<<"-";
       cout<<"\n";
       for(vg=0;vg<78;vg++)
     cout<<"-";
       cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tBED NO \t\t:-\t"<<bno;
       cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tNAME   \t\t:-\t"<<na;
       cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tGENDER \t\t:-\t"<<sex;
       cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tCITY   \t\t:-\t"<<city;
       cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tSTREET \t\t:-\t"<<street;

     }

    ~patient()
      {
        bno=0;
        year=0;
        date=0;
        month=0;
        strcpy(na,NULL);
        strcpy(city,NULL);
        strcpy(street,NULL);
        strcpy(sex,NULL);
      }};
void main()
  {
    patient p,p1;
    char ch,cna[20];
    xy:
    do
      {
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("file1.dat",ios::in);
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open("file1.dat",ios::app|ios::binary);
    ofstream temp;
    temp.open("temp1.dat",ios::app|ios::binary);
    clrscr();
    cout<<"\n\t\t\t***HOSPITAL MANAGEMENT SOFTWARE***"<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n\t\t\t  **Hospital Management Tasks**"<<"\n\n";
    for(int st=0;st<80;st++)
      cout<<"-";
    for(st=0;st<80;st++)
      cout<<"|";
    for(st=0;st<80;st++)
      cout<<"-";
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\tPlease  select a task to do...."<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t1. Enter a new patient information ."<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t2. View detail of existing patient ."<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t3. Emergency"<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t4. Discharge patient"<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t5. Exit from the program ."<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t6.ADMIN MODE"<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\tEnter your task serial :"<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
    ch=getche();
    switch(ch)
     {
       case '1': clrscr();
          p.enterdata();
          ofile.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
          getch();
          break;
       case '2':
          clrscr();
          int k=0,cbno=0;
          if(!ifile)
        {
          cout<<"\n unable to open file\n";
          getch();
        }
        else
        {
          cout<<"\n ENTER THE NAME OF PATIENT\t\t\t-----\t\t";gets(cna);
          cout<<"\n ENTER BED NUMBER\t\t\t\t-----\t\t";cin>>cbno;
          ifile.clear();
          ifile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
          while(!ifile.eof())
           {
             ifile.read((char*)&p1,sizeof(p1));
             if(cbno==p1.bno)
              {
             if(strcmpi(cna,p1.na)==0)
               {
                 p1.showdata();
                 getch();
                 k=1;
                 break;
               }
              }
           }
          if(k!=1)
          cout<<"\n NO SUCH RECORD PRESENT\n";
          getch();
        }
          ifile.close();
          break;
       case '3':
          clrscr();
          temp.clear();
          temp.seekp(0,ios::beg);
          ifile.clear();
          ifile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
          p1.enterdata();
          temp.write((char*)&p1,sizeof(p1));
          while(!ifile.eof())
        {
          ifile.read((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
          cout<<"\ndone writing\n";
          cout<<"\n done";getch();
          temp.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
        }
          ifile.close();
          temp.close();
          remove("file1.dat");
          rename("temp1.dat","file1.dat");
          break;

       case '4' :
          char ch;int pos=-1;
          clrscr();
          cout<<"\t\t\tDISCHARGE PATIENT\n";
          if(!ifile)
        { clrscr();
          cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t!!!!FAILED TO OPEN FILE!!!! \n";
          getch();
        }
        else
        {
           cout<<"\n ENTER THE NAME OF PATIENT\t\t\t-----\t\t";gets(cna);
           cout<<"\n ENTER BED NUMBER\t\t\t\t-----\t\t";cin>>cbno;
           ifile.clear();
           ifile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
           while(!ifile.eof())
            {
              ifile.read((char*)&p1,sizeof(p1));
              if(cbno==p1.bno)
            {
               if(strcmpi(cna,p1.na)==0)
            { pos=ifile.tellg();
              p1.showdata();
              cout<<"\n \t\t ARE YOU SURE TO DISCHARGE THIS PATIENT(y/n)? \n \t\t";
              ch=getche();
              getch();k=1;
              break;
            } }
           }
           if(k!=1)
          { cout<<"\n NO SUCH RECORD PRESENT\n";
           getch();
           ifile.close();
           goto xy;}
           ifile.close();
        if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
       {
          ifile.open("file1.dat");
           while(!ifile.eof())
        {
              ifile.read((char*)&p1,sizeof(p1));
               if(pos!=ifile.tellg())
              temp.write((char*)&p1,sizeof(p1));
         }
          ifile.close();
          temp.close();
          remove("file1.dat");


          rename("temp1.dat","file1.dat");
           } }

    break;
    case '5':
    break;


    case '6':
       char id[5];
       clrscr();
       cout<<"\n ENTER THE ADMIN ID\t\t----    ";
       gets(id);
       if(strcmp(id,"70176")==0)
      {
       cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t VERIFICATION SUCCESSFUL ";
       getch();
       if(!ifile)
    {cout<<"unable to open file";
    getch();}
    else
    {

            ifile.clear();
           ifile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
           while(!ifile.eof())
               {  ifile.read((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
               p.showdata();
               getch();
            }
      } ifile.close(); }else
    {  cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t!!!!!! FAILED TO VERIFY!!!!!!\n"; getch();}
      break;
      default :
      cout<<"\n ERROR \n";
      cout<<"\a";
      getch();
      break;}}
    while(ch!='5');
  }
```

if the code is not clear here is the link to download it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hTz3awCDaW-40ewEbpK1VHYa6k5SoD-d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 1) What is provided input? Expected/actual output? 2) Is this [mre]? It seems that, at the very least, output statements wouldn't be necessary to reproduce the issue. 3) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, while observing values of variables, at each execution step, to see where the code does something, that you didn't expect? 4) "_This is the first time i am using this site so please forgive me if i have posted this in a wrong way_" Did you take the [tour], and read through [ask], and [help], before asking? If not, why not?

Comment: 4.Yes I've taken the tour ... 3. I don't know how to use it but i tried and i found the problem is in the loop where it is reading the file content still i am unable to find any solution 2)??? I really have no idea what are you talking about ...1) for e.g. if i am entering "male" in sex, "almora" in city it is displaying only "ale" in sex and "lmora"in city

Comment: 4) I doubt that. Upon taking a [tour] - you receive a badge. Since you don't have any badges - I doubt that you taken it. You didn't answer if you read through [ask], and [help]. 3) Then learn how to use it - it is invaluable tool when developing, and no one is stopping you from learning it. 2) If you had read [ask], you will know, that [mre] is a requirement, when asking questions. In your case - emphasis is on **minimal**. 1) Please [edit] your question, to include all of the relevant information for it, instead of writing all of it in the comments.